# "Environnement connu" contre "Domaine d'intervention" dans un dossier de compétences

Tags: professions, curriculum-vitae

Après un entretien d'embauche, la consultante recrutement m'a envoyé par courriel un dossier de compétences que je dois remplir de façon à ne pas dépasser les 2 pages et ensuite lui renvoyer.

Celui-ci, entre autres, comporte deux rubriques : "Environnements connus" et "Domaines d’intervention".

La première ne doit pas avoir de connection avec l'informatique puisqu'il existe déjà une autre rubrique "Logiciels et systèmes".
J'ai cherché sur Internet mais n'en ai rien trouvé.

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer la différence entre "Environnements connus" et "Domaines d’intervention" dans ce contexte et me donner quelques exemples concrets et représentatifs  ?

Par exemple, avec quoi un docteur en mécanique ou bien un ingénieur généraliste  doit-il remplir la première et la seconde rubrique ?

Par souci d'exhausticité, voici toutes les rubriques à remplir :

> TITRE DU POSTE
>
> Diplômes :
>
> Logiciels et systèmes :
>
> Langues :
>
> Habilitations :
>
> ENVIRONNEMENTS CONNUS
>
> DOMAINES D’INTERVENTION
>
> RÉALISATIONS

En espérant que cela pourrait vous aider. Merci par avance.

Comment: On pourrait peut-être mieux comprendre ce qui est attendu si les autres rubriques, en particulier celles qui sont contiguës ou les parentes étaient indiquées dans la question. D'autre part, s'agit-t-il d'un questionnaire générique ou spécifique au type de poste proposé ?

Comment: @jlliagre : Merci pour ton commentaire. C'est un dossier de compétences à remplir de façon à ne pas dépasser 2 pages. Je vais actualiser ma question tout de suite.

Comment: @jlliagre : Je viens d'actualiser la question avec le contenu du dossier. Merci encore !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le questionnaire est orienté vers des postes d'ingénieurs en informatique.

*Environnements connus* permet à ces derniers d'indiquer des systèmes d'exploitation comme *Windows*, *Linux*, *Android*, etc. ou des [*environnements de développement*](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environnement_de_d%C3%A9veloppement) comme *Eclipse*.

Answer (score 2):

Il semble que "Environnements connus" doive concerner les sujets de connaissance générale et  "Domaines d’intervention" les sujets dans lesquels le candidat est arrivé à une certaine spécialisation et a été capable d'effectuer un travail personnel, ou bien dans lesquels il se trouve en mesure de se lancer dans un travail personnel ne nécessitant pas une étude importante ou une revue importante des principes. Cependant, je crois qu'il vaut mieux demander des précisions à l'employeur, cela au vu que ces termes ne sont pas courants ;  la signification est un peu une affaire de devinette.
Un courriel demandant de quoi il est  question précisément ne devrait pas être un problème (en mentionnant ce que l'on croit être le sens, peut être).

Comment: Je viens d'actualiser la question en donnant plus de détails. Merci pour la réponse.